# Reputation for 'marked as answer' not credited

Tags: support

Today a response by me [Matlab user guides in Kindle format](https://superuser.com/questions/242041/matlab-user-guides-in-kindle-format) was marked as answer and also upvoted .
The upvote was credited but the reputation points for marked as answer was not

Answer (score 3):

I'm looking at your rep on the reputation tab of your user profile and I see it got credited 8 hours ago. Try going to http://www.superuser.com/reputation and clicking the recalculate button on the bottom to manually recalculate your rep. You could also try deleting your cookies.

[image]

Comment: recalculation brought it 3 points lower :)